# Saving PFObject throws exception

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfobject, pfuser

I have defined my own class `MYPFObject` to wrap a `PFObject` with all the apis like `saveInbackground` methods directing it to internal `PFObject`'s `saveinbackground`. This is to decouple my Parse code from rest of my code into one model layer.
The `[PFUser currentUser]` is valid and logged in.

But While saving a `PFObject` containing pointers to currentUser and some other user throws exception.

```
Caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException" with reason "User cannot be saved unless they have been authenticated via logIn or signUp":
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018514c2f4 <redacted> + 160
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001969180e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018514c218 <redacted> + 0
    3                                       0x00000001004bc980 -[PFUser(Private) _checkSaveParametersWithCurrentUser:] + 380
    4                                       0x0000000100466f3c __65+[PFObject(Private) _deepSaveAsync:withCurrentUser:sessionToken:]_block_invoke_3 + 412
    5                                       0x000000010062e628 __41-[BFTask continueWithExecutor:withBlock:]_block_invoke_2 + 32
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001010d8fd4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001010d8f94 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001010e6b54 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2180
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001010e8248 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000019714922c _pthread_wqthread + 816
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000197148ef0 start_wqthread + 4
).
```

Comment: You say the user is logged in, but the error says otherwise. Are you logging any errors from the login process?

Comment: How are you creating the 'other' users?

Comment: Login has no problem because some of the saves work fine. Only when my Parse table has two pointers say for example trying to save an "object" with pointers to two Users - buyer and seller, it throws this exception. My old code had PFObject and Parse code scattered everywhere which worked fine. But now I m just trying to add a simple wrapper/adapter to my PFObject and PFUser which has pfObject as a property and will direct all the calls like saveInBackground etc to this internal pfObject of this wrapper class.

Comment: I m trying to create a simple wrapper TSObject with same api as PFObject
//self.item is a TSObject.
TSUser *seller_ = [self.item objectForKey:@"user"];
TSObject *tsObj_ = [TSObject objectWithClassName:@"MyClassName"];
    [tsObj_ setObject:[TSUser currentUser] forKey:@"buyer"];
    [tsObj_ setObject:seller_ forKey:@"seller"]; //setObject is a TSObject api method which internally unwraps the PFObject and sets it to tsObj_.pfObject's setObject.
//THIS  LINE THEN THROWS THAT BIG EXCEPTION   
 [tsObj_ saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
         [self.hud hide:YES];}];

Comment: @implementation TSObject
+ (id)objectWithClassName:(NSString *)aCls {
    TSObject *obj_ = [[TSObject alloc] init];
    obj_.pfObj = [PFObject objectWithClassName:aCls];
    obj_.objectId = obj_.pfObj.objectId;
    return obj_;
}
+ (id)initWithPFObject: (PFObject *) aPFObject {
    TSObject *obj_ = [[TSObject alloc] init];
    obj_.pfObj = aPFObject;
    obj_.objectId = obj_.pfObj.objectId;
    obj_.createdAt = obj_.pfObj.createdAt; return obj_;
}
- (id)objectForKey:(NSString *)key {
    return [self getObjectWrapper:[self.pfObj objectForKey:key]];
}

Comment: continue TsObject - (void)setObject:(id)object forKey:(NSString *)key { [self.pfObject setObject:[self getInsideObj:object] forKey:key];}-(id) getObjWrapper : (id) aObj {
    if([aObject isKindOfClass:[PFUser class]]) {
        TSUser *tsObj_ = [TSUser initWithPFUser:aObj];
        return tsObj_; }if([aObject isKindOfClass:[PFObject class]]) {
        TSObject *tsObj_ = [TSObject initWithPFObject:aObj];
        return tsObj_;}return aObj;}-(id) getInsideObj : (id) obj_ {
    if([obj_ is TSUser) 
         return [obj_ getPFUser];
    else if([obj_ is TSObject]) 
        return [obj_ getPFObj];}

Comment: Faced exactly the same problem. But in my case the situation is even funny - I have two very similar methods, both creates and saves the objects of the same class but with different property values. And what? The first method works like a charm, the second - crashes. I spent half a day trying to resolve the problem, but without success.

Comment: This got resolved for me. The issue was that somewhere in my model initialization I was doing obj.username = self.pfUser.username. But with this self.pfUser got marked as dirty. It's isDirty method returned me true. Thats why any saveInBackground operations involving that user (not the current user) tried to save that user first which failed because of ACL. Removing that line worked fine. It is so strange that why PFUser class might mark the object dirty just after trying to read its username property. I m not even saving it.